# Getting the value of a textfield in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, material-design

I have a simple paper-input that I'm trying to get the value from but for some reason I'm not having any luck. Here's a simplified version of the HTML where I set up the button and the onclick event:

```
  <paper-action-dialog id="addAnnotation" transition="paper-dialog-transition-center">
        <core-header-panel flex id="annotation-box">
            <core-toolbar class="graph-sets-header">
              <span flex>TEST</span>
            </core-toolbar>
            <br>
            <paper-input-decorator label="Add your annotation">
                <paper-autogrow-textarea>
                    <textarea id="annotationSource"></textarea>
                </paper-autogrow-textarea>
            </paper-input-decorator>
            <paper-button dismissive hover >Cancel</paper-button>
            <paper-button affirmative hover onclick="getAnnotation()">Submit</paper-button>
        </core-header-panel>
    </paper-action-dialog>
```

and here's my JS function:

```
function getAnnotation(){

    var toolText = document.getElementById('annotationSource').value;
        console.log(toolText);

}
```

Here's a plunker with most of it running (except I can't get the value of the paper-input to show in the console: http://plnkr.co/edit/1PAi13ISgP7mNXDMNStF?p=preview

I'm sure  could make this a polymer template, but I need to pass the value to a bunch of other functions in the main HTML and I keep having problems with moving data in and out of a template so I'd like to avoid that if I can.

**Adding some more flow to make it clearer***
To bring up the annotation box you need to click on any of the points on the graph in the plunker - doing so brings up the paper-input box, which I want to use to create an annotation... eventually adding the annotation text to a tooltip that will appear by doing a mouse over on the dot that I generate

Comment: Trying the Plunker: If I type 'foo' into the paper-input and hit submit it logs in my console.

Comment: Weird that was an old plunker that I somehow didn't fork correctly - this is the correct one (http://plnkr.co/edit/1PAi13ISgP7mNXDMNStF?p=preview) will update in main body as well

Comment: plunker bin still seemed messed up

Comment: Sorry I realized the instructions on how to bring up the paper-dialog weren't very clear - added more detailed instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a template using 'auto-binding' it's easier to access the annotationSource element

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#graph',
    padding: {
      top: 30
    },
    data: {
      xs: {
        'data1': 'x1',
        'data2': 'x2',
      },
      columns: [
        ['x1', 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10],
        ['x2', 3, 5, 7, 10, 12],
        ['data1', 2, 3, 6, 7.5, 8, 9.5],
        ['data2', 2, 4, 4.5, 10, 11]
      ],

      onclick: function(d, i) {
        console.log("onclick", d, i);
        console.log(i.getAttribute('cx'));
        var setCX = Number(i.getAttribute('cx'));

        document.getElementById("someTemplate").$.addAnnotation.toggle()

        var svg = d3.select("svg");

        var circle = svg.append("circle")
          .attr("cy", 10)
          .attr("cx", (setCX + 40))
          .attr("r", 5);

      }
    }
  });

  function getAnnotation() {

    var annotationSource = document.getElementById("someTemplate").$.annotationSource;
    var toolText = annotationSource.value;

    console.log(toolText);

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.min.js?20141211"></script>
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html" rel="import">
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dialog/paper-action-dialog.html" rel="import">
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html" rel="import">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/paper-autogrow-textarea.html">
<link href="http://c3js.org/css/c3-b03125fa.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://c3js.org/js/d3.min-3bff8220.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://c3js.org/js/c3.min-78d63552.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<template id="someTemplate" is="auto-binding">

  <paper-action-dialog id="addAnnotation" transition="paper-dialog-transition-center">
    <core-header-panel flex id="annotation-box">
      <core-toolbar class="graph-sets-header">
        <span flex>TEST</span>
      </core-toolbar>
      <br>
      <paper-input-decorator label="Add your annotation">
        <paper-autogrow-textarea>
          <textarea id="annotationSource"></textarea>
        </paper-autogrow-textarea>
      </paper-input-decorator>
      <paper-button dismissive hover>Cancel</paper-button>
      <paper-button affirmative hover onclick="getAnnotation()">Submit</paper-button>
    </core-header-panel>
  </paper-action-dialog>

</template>

<div id="graph">
</div>
```

Comment: So this is a dumb question (as I'm still learning the ropes on Polymer) - Does putting a template in the middle of an otherwise "normal" html page cause any problems?

Answer (score 1):

ok without using a template I've used the window.event to obtain the paper button element that is being clicked, then from there grabbed the annotation-box element then used querySelector to get the annotationSource element. There maybe a better way but it works

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
   bindto: '#graph',
   padding: {
     top: 30
   },
   data: {
     xs: {
       'data1': 'x1',
       'data2': 'x2',
     },
     columns: [
       ['x1', 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10],
       ['x2', 3, 5, 7, 10, 12],
       ['data1', 2, 3, 6, 7.5, 8, 9.5],
       ['data2', 2, 4, 4.5, 10, 11]
     ],

     onclick: function(d, i) {
       console.log("onclick", d, i);
       console.log(i.getAttribute('cx'));
       var setCX = Number(i.getAttribute('cx'));
       document.querySelector('#addAnnotation').toggle()

       var svg = d3.select("svg");

       var circle = svg.append("circle")
         .attr("cy", 10)
         .attr("cx", (setCX + 40))
         .attr("r", 5);

     }
   }
 });

 function getAnnotation() {

   var paperBtnElement = window.event.toElement || window.event.relatedTarget || window.event.target;
   var toolText = paperBtnElement.parentElement.querySelector("#annotationSource").value;
   console.log(toolText);

 }
```

```css
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 12px;
  padding: 8px;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background: #ddd;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.min.js?20141211"></script>
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html" rel="import">
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dialog/paper-action-dialog.html" rel="import">
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html" rel="import">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/paper-autogrow-textarea.html">

<link href="http://c3js.org/css/c3-b03125fa.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://c3js.org/js/d3.min-3bff8220.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://c3js.org/js/c3.min-78d63552.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<paper-action-dialog id="addAnnotation" transition="paper-dialog-transition-center">
  <core-header-panel flex id="annotation-box">
    <core-toolbar class="graph-sets-header">
      <span flex>TEST</span>
    </core-toolbar>
    <br>
    <paper-input-decorator label="Add your annotation">
      <paper-autogrow-textarea>
        <textarea id="annotationSource"></textarea>
      </paper-autogrow-textarea>
    </paper-input-decorator>
    <paper-button dismissive hover>Cancel</paper-button>
    <paper-button affirmative hover onclick="getAnnotation()">Submit</paper-button>
  </core-header-panel>
</paper-action-dialog>

<div id="graph">
</div>
```